# php remove time from custom datetime formatting

Tags: php

How could I set the `isClean` to automatically remove the time if its set to: 00:00:00. So if a time hasn't been set or midnight then dont display anything.

```
/**
 * Perform datetime formatting operations.
 * - relative: if today/yesterday
 * - clean: remove time if 00:00
 *
 * @param string $var
 * @param string||array $params
 * @return string
 */
protected function datetime($var,$params) {
    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
    // 1970-01-01 00:00:00
    $template = $params;
    $isRelative = false;
    $isClean = false;
    if (is_array($params) && !empty($params['template'])) {
        if (!empty($params['relative']) && trim(strtolower($params['relative'])) == 'yes') {
            $isRelative = true;
        }
        if (!empty($params['clean']) && trim(strtolower($params['clean'])) == 'yes') {
            $isClean = true;
        }
        $template = $params['template'];
    }

    // check if its empty or not?
    if(strlen($var)<1) return $var;

    // ignore invalue request throw error?
    if(is_array($template)) return $var;

    if($var == "NOW") $var = date("d-m-Y H:i:s");

    $out = $var;
    if(strpos($out,":") === false) {
        $out = trim($out);
        $out .= " 00:00:00";
    }

    if(($timestamp = $this->getTimestamp($out)) !== false) {
        if ($isRelative) {
            $time = date('H:i', $timestamp);
            if (date('Ymd') == date('Ymd', $timestamp)) {
                // Today
                return sprintf("Today at %s", $time);
            } else {
                // Yesterday?
                $today = strtotime("12:00:00");
                $yesterday = strtotime('-1 day', $today);

                if (abs($yesterday - $timestamp) < 12*3600) {
                    return sprintf("Yesterday at %s", $time);
                }
            }
        }

        $var = date($template,$timestamp);
    }

    return $var;
}
```

More info: our CMS works by reading the `<match>` and automatically matching this to the database column name OR we manually write `<format>long_datetime</format>`.

So the main reason for this method is to :

> 1. Connect the XML options with php datetime.
> 2. Add extra functionality such as NOW, relative dates and now the ability to clean up the datetime if set to 0s

Comment: Use DateTime objects will solve a lot of that headache

Comment: Too many code for such a simple task .....

Comment: Also, I'm not 100% understanding the purpose of this function. What is the expected input and output?

Comment: Can we leave your code and just understand what you want ... am sure it can be done simpler @John Magnolia

Comment: @Baba I wouldn't really want to start again with this code because I know it already works on previous projects/old php versions. I would prefer to adapt the code so its possible

Comment: @John Magnolia Ok what do you mean by `to automatically remove the time`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request is not clear but with clarification on `$var` and `to automatically remove the time` am sure this would help

```
$xml = '
<patterns>
        <pattern>
    <match>date</match>
    <datetime>d/m/Y</datetime>
</pattern>

<pattern>
    <match>datetime</match>
    <datetime>d/m/Y H:i</datetime>
</pattern>

<pattern>
    <match>datetime_nice</match>
    <datetime>jS F Y, H:i</datetime>
</pattern>

<pattern>
    <match>datetime_iso</match>
    <datetime>c</datetime>
</pattern>

<pattern>
    <match>datetime_relative</match>
    <datetime>
        <relative>YES</relative>
        <clean>yes</clean>
        <template>jS M y, H:i</template>
    </datetime>
</pattern>

<pattern>
    <match>date_relative</match>
    <datetime>
        <relative>yes</relative>
        <template>jS M, Y</template>
    </datetime>
</pattern>

<pattern>
    <match>long_datetime</match>
    <datetime>
        <relative>YES</relative>
        <template>jS M Y \a\t H:i</template>
    </datetime>
</pattern>
</patterns>     
';

echo simpleDateTime("long_datetime",$xml);
```

Output

```
Yesterday at 11th Oct 12 
                          ^--- Date was cleaned instead of H:i in the template
```

Function Used

```
function simpleDateTime($var, $xml) {
    $list = getList($xml);
    $list = $list[$var];
    $date = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone("Europe/London"));
    $output = $date->format($list['template']);
    if ($list['clean'] === true) {
        $date->setTime(0, 0, 0);
        $output = str_replace("00:00", "", $date->format($list['template']));
    }
    $output = trim($output);
    $output = rtrim($output, ",");
    if ($list['reletive'] === false) {
        return sprintf("Today at %s", $output);
    } else {
        $date->modify("+1 day");
        return sprintf("Yesterday at %s", $output);
    }
}

function getList($xml) {
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
    $list = array();
    foreach ( $xml->children() as $pattern ) {
        $item = array();
        $item['reletive'] = false;
        $item['clean'] = false;

        if (isset($pattern->datetime->template)) {
            $item['reletive'] = (strtoupper($pattern->datetime->relative) == "YES") ? true : false;
            $item['clean'] = (strtoupper($pattern->datetime->clean) == "YES") ? true : false;
            $item['template'] = (string) $pattern->datetime->template;
        } else {
            $item['template'] = (string) $pattern->datetime;
        }

        $list[(string) $pattern->match] = $item;
    }
    return $list;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this isn't what I was looking for or anything like how it works now. I will try to remove the XML into a simple array, maybe this is the part which is confusing and show output examples so you can better understand.

Comment: let me know when you have examples and output ... @John Magnolia

Comment: Just updated the answer with extra debug data, hopefully this helps

Comment: @John Magnolia those are minor corrections ... see updated code